# Place UIElement and Text in same line in RichTextbox

Tags: wpf, button, text, richtextbox, uielement

How to place text and Button in a same line in WPF Richtextbox?

In the image below some texts and a button control are placed in a richtextbox.

[image]

I want some texts to be placed before and after the button in the same line.

Is it possible to define some width to the blockuicontainer or a wayout to achieve the same?

What I want is:

[image]

Comment: Oo Some additional information would be helpful. How about a scribble?

Comment: I have added brief description of my question.

Comment: It's still unclear. Do you want to have the text flowing around the `Button`, because you only have one large text? Are there two texts, so that you can have one `TextBox` before and one after the `Button`?

Comment: I have edited the image to show what I want. Please have a look again.
These are simple texts(not textboxes) before and after the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a `FlowDocument` to the `RichTextBox` and a `Paragraph` to the `FlowDocument`.

Sample code is:

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
        fd.Blocks.Add(para);
        txtExpression.Document = fd;
        para.Inlines.Add(new Button() { Content = "Hello!" });
```

Comment: what is the use of this approach if the button is not clickable

Comment: it is clickable.